# A structure sheaf for real analytification of semialgebraic sets in the context of signed tropicalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry, berkovich-geometry, real-algebra

Let $X=Spec(A)$ be an affine scheme, where $A$ be a commutative algebra over a non-archimedean valued field $K$. Assume that $K$ is a real closed field with the unique ordering $<$, which should be compatible with the absolute value $|\cdot|_K$ (i.e. it holds: $0<f\leq g$ iff $|f|_K\leq |g|_K$).
Now in the paper [Real tropicalization and analytification of semialgebraic sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05132) by Philipp Jell, Claus Scheiderer and Josephine Yu, the authors introduced the concept of a real analytification $X^{an}_r:= $ of $X$, which is basically an amalgation of the two following two familiar spaces:

1. The Berkovich spectrum $X^{an}=\mathcal{M}(A)$, consisting of all bounded real semivaluations $|\cdot|_x$ on $A$ extending $|\cdot|_K$, and
2. the real spectrum $X_r=Sper(A)$, consisting of all prime orderings $<_x$ on $A$.

The authors have shown that in the affine case $X^{an}_r$ can be described by the signed seminorms $|\cdot|^{sgn}_x$ (satisfying $|f|^{sgn}_x=sgn_x(f)|f|_K$) of $A$, and study the relation two the two classical spaces above. In particular, they showed that our new space inherits the nice topological properties of the Berkokovich spectrum, which they used to define a notion of tropicalization of semialgebraic subsets of $X(K)$. There exists a canonical map $\psi: X^{an}_r\to X_r$. If $M\subseteq X(K)$ is a semialgebraic subset, we call $M^{an}_r:=\psi^{-1}(\tilde{M})$ the real analytification of $M$, where $\tilde{M}$ is the abstraction of $M$.

I'm now wondering if it might be possible to endow these spaces $M^{an}_r$ (or more generally real analytifications of constructible subsets) with a nice structure sheaf. One could try to combine the structure sheaves of its parents:

1. Let $U\subseteq \mathcal{M}(A)$ be an open subset. We call a subset $Z\subseteq U$ special, if it can  be written as $Z=\cup^n_{i=1}D_i$ where $D_i$ is an $k$-affinoid subdomain ([Definition 13.10 in Mattias Jonsson's course over Berkovich spaces](https://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Etakumim/Berkovich.pdf)). We associate to $Z$ the affinoid $K$-algebra $A_Z:=ker(\Pi_i A_{D_i}\to \Pi_{i,j}A_{D_i\cap D_j})$. Then by setting
   $$\mathcal{O}(U):=lim_{Z\subseteq U special}A_Z$$
   we obtain a sheaf on $\mathcal{M}(A)$ (with respect to the special G-topology).
2. On a constructible subset $S\subseteq sper(A)$ there exists a sheaf of semialgebraic function developed by Niels Schwart in his Habilitationsschrift [The Basic Theory of Real Closed Spaces](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=il_UCQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR4&dq=Niels%20Schwartz&ots=fPdkNMVESf&sig=ibA518J-uLvz3z8y13GFd34Q5Dg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Niels%20Schwartz&f=false). I will give a sketch of his construction. Let $\alpha,\beta\in S$ where $\beta$ is a specialization of $\alpha$. Then $supp(\beta)/supp(\alpha)\triangleleft A/supp(\alpha)$ is a convex prime ideal, such that there exists the largest convex subring $C_{\alpha\beta}\subset k(\alpha)$ with $supp(\beta)/ supp(\alpha)=\mathcal{m}_{\alpha\beta}\cap A/supp(\alpha)$. Denote $k(\alpha,\beta):=C_{\alpha\beta}/\mathcal{m}_{\alpha\beta}$, which is a real closed field with the canonical mapping $\lambda_{\alpha\beta}:C_{\alpha\beta}\to k(\alpha,\beta)$. Note that the monotone embedding $A/supp(\beta)\to k(\alpha,\beta)$ extends uniquely to $k(\beta)\subset k(\alpha,\beta)$.
   Now we define the ring of compatible families $U_{A,S}(S)$ as the set of all families $f\in\Pi_{\alpha\in S}k(\alpha)$ such that for all $\alpha,\beta\in S$, where $\beta$ is a specialization of $\alpha$, we have: $f(\alpha)\in C_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\lambda_{\alpha\beta}(f(\alpha))=f(\beta)$. Now consider the subring $$R(S):=\lbrace f\in U_{A,S}(S)\mid \forall g\in A(S)\left[ f\right]: P(g)~is~constructible\rbrace$$,
   where $P(g):=\lbrace \alpha\in S\mid g(\alpha)\geq 0\rbrace$ and $A(S)$ denotes the image of the canonical homomorphism $$\rho_S: A\to \Pi_{\alpha\in S}k(\alpha), f\mapsto (f(\alpha))_{\alpha\in S}.$$
   We can consider the affine scheme $Spec(R(S))$ associated to $R(S)$. By Theorem 3.10 auf Schwart' paper the canonical map $supp: Sper(R(S))\to Spec(R(S)), \alpha\mapsto supp(\alpha)$ is a homeomorphism, so that we can consider the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{Spec(R(S))}$ as sheaf on $Sper(R(S))$. Now we call $R_{A,S}:=\mathcal{O}_{Spec(R(S))\mid S}$ the sheaf of semialgebraic function on $S$, which makes $S$ into a locally ringed space.

My question now is whether we can possibly combine these two sheaves to become a sheaf for a real analytified constructible subset $S^{an}_r$, or if there might be another way to achieve this goal.